# Push commit from local branch A to branch B when branch A was merged to branch B in GIT

Tags: git, github, version-control, merge, commit

The situation is almost described in the header:

1. I had branch A and branch B
2. Branch A was merged into branch B
3. I commited locally to branch A

How can I move local commits from branch A to branch B without losing them?

Comment: did you get it working?

Comment: yes, I created new branch from my local files, pushed it and than merged. The question was about some "moving tool" in git, to "move" commits like some blocks of data. 
Maybe that's weird but I looked for that.

Answer (score 0):

Think of branches as pointers to commits, because in fact, that's what they are.

The fact they were merged before doesn't change anything: A's pointer points to the merge commit during step 2 and during step 3 it moves to point to the new commit. Meanwhile B's pointer is still pointing to the latest B commit (the one before the merge).

Now you want to make B's pointer point to the same commit as A's. You can do it 2 ways, one way is:

```
git checkout B
git merge A
```

This will get A's changes by [fast-forwarding](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Basic-Branching-and-Merging) B's pointer to where A is.

The other way would be to checkout to A and reset B to A, but I really don't recommend if you don't fully understand what's going on.